# PHP no funciona al traer datos de una base de datos

Tags: php, sql, formularios

```
<?php
require_once('bdd.php');


$sql = "SELECT * FROM events ";

$req = $bdd->prepare($sql);
$req->execute();

$events = $req->fetchAll();

?>
```

despues de hacer la conexion con mi base de datos uso este codigo para retornar los valores en una ventana modal para editarlos.

El problema es que solo me trae 1 de los muchos valores en el modal.

y pueden verlo aqui.
http://prensaalcaldiadearismendi.epizy.com/
cuando se presiona doble click en un evento.

mi input de ingreso y retorno de datos es este

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label for="color" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Importancia</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <select name="color" class="form-control importancia" id="color" disabled>
                          <option value="">SELECCIONAR</option>
                          <option style="color:#000;" value="#000">&#9724; SIN TRASCENDENCIA</option>
                          <option style="color:#008000;" value="#008000">&#9724; IMPORTANTE</option>
                          <option style="color:#FF0000;" value="#FF0000">&#9724; ULTIMA HORA</option>
                          <option style="color:#40E0D0;" value="#40E0D0">&#9724; EFEMERIDES</option>
                           <option style="color:#FFD700;" value="#FFD700">&#9724; OTROS</option>


                        </select>  
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

lo que no entiendo es por que no se me colocan los datos en la ventana de edicion.

aqui el resto del codigo

```
var date = new Date();
var yyyy = date.getFullYear().toString();
var mm = (date.getMonth()+1).toString().length == 1 ? "0"+(date.getMonth()+1).toString() : (date.getMonth()+1).toString();
var dd  = (date.getDate()).toString().length == 1 ? "0"+(date.getDate()).toString() : (date.getDate()).toString();

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
         language: 'es',
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay',

    },
    defaultDate: yyyy+"-"+mm+"-"+dd,
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    select: function(start, end) {

        $('#ModalAdd #start').val(moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
        $('#ModalAdd #end').val(moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
        $('#ModalAdd').modal('show');
    },
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
        element.bind('dblclick', function() {
            $('#ModalEdit #id').val(event.id);
            $('#ModalEdit #title').val(event.title);
            $('#ModalEdit #color').val(event.color);
            $('#ModalEdit').modal('show');
        });
    },
    eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) { // si changement de position

        edit(event);

    },
    eventResize: function(event,dayDelta,minuteDelta,revertFunc) { // si changement de longueur

        edit(event);

    },
    events: [
    <?php foreach($events as $event): 

        $start = explode(" ", $event['start']);
        $end = explode(" ", $event['end']);
        if($start[1] == '00:00:00'){
            $start = $start[0];
        }else{
            $start = $event['start'];
        }
        if($end[1] == '00:00:00'){
            $end = $end[0];
        }else{
            $end = $event['end'];
        }
    ?>
        {
            id: '<?php echo $event['id']; ?>',
            title: '<?php echo $event['title']; ?>',
            start: '<?php echo $start; ?>',
            end: '<?php echo $end; ?>',
            color: '<?php echo $event['color']; ?>',
            lugar: '<?php echo $event['lugar']; ?>',
        },
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    ]
});

function edit(event){
    start = event.start.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
    if(event.end){
        end = event.end.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
    }else{
        end = start;
    }

    id =  event.id;

    Event = [];
    Event[0] = id;
    Event[1] = start;
    Event[2] = end;

    $.ajax({
     url: 'editEventDate.php',
     type: "POST",
     data: {Event:Event},
     success: function(rep) {
            if(rep == 'OK'){
                alert('Evento se ha guardado correctamente');
            }else{
                alert('No se pudo guardar. Inténtalo de nuevo.'); 
            }
        }
    });
}

});
```

Comment: ¿Dónde manejas la respuesta de la consulta a la base de datos para mostrarla en el modal? ¿Qué estás usando Ajax/jQuery? ¿Cómo deberían mostrarse los datos, paginados, uno por uno con un botón de `Próximo / Anterior` o algo así? Muchas cosas no quedan clara en la pregunta. Yo ni siquiera usaría un modal, sino que mostraría la respuesta en una sección de la misma página desde la cual lanzo la consulta.

Comment: usando Ajax . 
quiero mostrar los datos solamente cuando se le de doble click al elemento .
quiero hacerlo asi @A.Cedano usando esos modales.

Comment: ya actualice la pregunta, alli esta el codigo @A.Cedano

Comment: En esta parte `success: function(rep) {` tienes que usar lo que trae `rep`, suponiendo que está funcionando bien y trae los datos que esperas, y mostrarlos en el modal. Aunque como te decía, los modales van cayendo en desuso y constituyen hoy día una mala experiencia de usuario. Con Ajax tú puedes perfectamente habilitar un área del propio DOM desde el que hiciste la llamada a Ajax para mostrar la respuesta.